# Attenuation in microwave and optical communications

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-engineering, fiber-optics, microwaves

I have read that the attenuations of microwave transmission lines and optical fibers are ~1 db/m and ~ 0.2 db/km, respectively. I understand that these values depend on the geometry, design, and frequency of the carrier signals.

However, I was wondering if there is an inherently physical reason behind such a stark difference?

Also, according to this [reference](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3289128_High-speed_low-temperature-grown_GaAs_p-i-n_traveling-wave_photodetector/figures?lo=1), the attenuation of microwave channels should go up with frequency, thereby naively, if the same formulae are used at optical frequencies, that should yield much higher attenuation.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about the answer to this, but it might be because transmission lines/waveguides and fibers confine the wave in different ways. Transmission lines use conductors, where the RF sheet resistance and hence conductor losses depend on conductivity and also increase with frequency. AFAIK optical fibers rely on total internal reflection at a dielectric interface, which is practically lossless.

Comment: metals are lossier at microwaves than infrared in glass.

Comment: @Puk total internal reflection is almost lossless but the dielectric absorption is per unit length along the fiber as the wave propagates